# .NET Blazor MAUI Hybrid App - IStringLocalizer not updating Language

Tags: localization, blazor, maui, .net-8.0

I have a .NET 8 Blazor MAUI Hybrid App that i develop in Visual Studio 2022.

I use Radzen.

I'm currently trying to implement changing the language whilst the Application is running.

So i implemented a `SettingsPage.razor` like so

```cs
@page "/settings"
@using MyApp.Components.Layout

<RadzenRow Gap="2rem" Class="rz-p-0 rz-p-lg-4">
    <RadzenColumn Size="12" SizeMD="6">
        <RadzenStack>
            <RadzenFieldset Text="@Localizer["SETTINGS"]">
                <RadzenStack Gap="1rem">
                    <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                        <LanguageChanger/>
                    </RadzenRow>
                    <RadzenRow AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
                        <ThemeChanger/>
                    </RadzenRow>
                </RadzenStack>
            </RadzenFieldset>
        </RadzenStack>
    </RadzenColumn>
</RadzenRow>
```

`LanguageChanger.razor`

```cs
@using MyApp.Services

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<RadzenColumn Size="5">
    <RadzenLabel 
        Text="@Localizer["LANGUAGE"]" 
        Component="LanguageSelector"
        Style="width: 100%"
    />
</RadzenColumn>
<RadzenColumn Size="7">
    <RadzenDropDown 
        @bind-Value="@LocalizationService.CurrentCulture" 
        Change="() => NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.Uri, false)"
        Data=@LocalizationService.AvailableCultures 
        TextProperty="DisplayName"
        Name="LanguageSelector"
        Style="width: 100%" />
</RadzenColumn>
```

`ThemeChanger.razor`:

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<RadzenColumn Size="5">
    <RadzenLabel 
        Text="@Localizer["THEME"]"
        Component="ThemeSelector"
        Style="width: 100%" />
</RadzenColumn>
<RadzenColumn Size="7">
    <RadzenDropDown 
        @bind-Value="currentTheme" 
        Change="@(args => ChangeTheme((Theme)args))"
        Data="@availableThemes"
        TextProperty="Name"
        Name="ThemeSelector"
        Style="width: 100%" />
</RadzenColumn>

@code
{
    List<Theme> availableThemes;
    Theme currentTheme;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        availableThemes = new ()
        {
            new (){ Name = "Material Light", FileName = "material" },
            new (){ Name = "Dark", FileName = "dark" }
        };

        var currentThemeName = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCurrentTheme");

        currentTheme = availableThemes.First(t => t.FileName.Equals(currentThemeName));
    }

    public class Theme
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }

    private async Task ChangeTheme(Theme theme)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("changeTheme", theme.FileName);
    }
}
```

`LocalisationService.cs`

```cs
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyApp.Services
{
    public class LocalizationService
    {
        public const string PREFERENCES_LANGUAGE_KEY = "language";

        public event Action OnLocalizationChanged;

        public static List<CultureInfo> AvailableCultures = new ()
        {
            // First in the list will be default value when starting the application and no thing is set in the Maui.Storage.Preferences

            // Resources/Languages/Language.de-DE.resx
            new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
            // Resources/Languages/Language.en-US.resx
            new CultureInfo("en-US")
        };

        public CultureInfo CurrentCulture
        {
            get => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            set
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = value;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = value;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = value;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = value;
                Preferences.Set(PREFERENCES_LANGUAGE_KEY, value.Name);

                // Trigger the event
                OnLocalizationChanged?.Invoke();
            }
        }

        public LocalizationService()
        {
            var language = Preferences.Get(PREFERENCES_LANGUAGE_KEY, AvailableCultures.FirstOrDefault()?.Name);

            if (language != null)
            {
                CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also i added the following resource files (.resx) in `Resources/Languages`

- Language.de-DE.resx
- Language.en-US.resx
- Language.resx

`IStringLocalizer` and the `LocalizationService` are registered in my `MauiProgram.cs` like so:

```cs
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LocalizationService>();
```

Lastly i import some injectable Services globally in my `_Imports.razor`

```cs
@* Radzen *@
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor

@* Localization *@
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using MyApp.Resources.Languages
@inject IStringLocalizer<Language> Localizer

@* Inject LocalizationService globally to set the potentially stored language *@
@using MyApp.Services
@inject LocalizationService LocalizationService
```

## Problem

When i select a new `CultureInfo` from the `RadzenDropDown` in the `LanguageChanger` the text `Localizer["LANGUAGE"]` of the `RadzenLabel` changes as it is intended...

But neither the `Localizer["THEME"]` of the `ThemeChanger.razor` changes nor the `Localizer["SETTINGS"]` of the  `SettingsPage.razor`...

Strangely all the Localizer["XYZ"] i use in my `MainLayout.razor` change...

Can someone figure out what is the problem here?

Comment: Did you mean the Language can't keep updating when you go to other razor page? You can refer to this case: [Can't keep CultureInfo across pages on .Net Maui Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73474199/cant-keep-cultureinfo-across-pages-on-net-maui-blazor).

Comment: No i mean i have a SettingsPage where i use my Components LanguageChanger.razor AND ThemeChanger.razor both havin a label `Text="@Localizer["XYZ"]"`

When the Language changes the label of the LanguageChanger changes but the label of the ThemeChanger doesnt

Comment: Did the ThemeChanger.razor has the same code as the LanguageChanger.razor?

Comment: From the Layout yes pretty the same. First a `RadzenColumn` with a `RadzenLabel` and then another `RadzenColumn`  with a `RadzenDropDown`

Comment: Did you also inject the LocalizationService for the `ThemeChanger.razor `?

Comment: Yes i inject it in my `_Imports.razor` so it should be globally available... its registered as singleton in my `MauiProgram.cs`

services.AddSingleton<LocalizationService>();

Comment: Did you try to change the [XYZ] to other words? The XYZ in en is same as in de.

Comment: XYZ was just an example actually it is Text="@Localizer["THEME"]" 
In german its "Farbschema" and in english ts just "Theme"

Comment: Could you please show the detail code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ok i changed my Question and gave a whole outline of my code... Hope that helps

Comment: Did you try use the native control not the Radzen?